# Oracle: How can I add ROWDEPENDENCIES to an existing table?

Tags: oracle

If I have a table t

```
create table t (x var number);
```

How can I modify the table so that it appears to have been created with `rowdependencies`?

```
create table t (x var number) rowdependencies;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't (unless something has changed in 12c that I'm not aware of).  You'll have to recreate the table with `rowdependencies` and move all the data from the old table to the new one.

Of course, you could use the `dbms_redefinition` package to do this redefinition online.  But under the covers, you'd still be creating a new table with `rowdependencies` enabled, copying the data over, dropping the old table and renaming the new one.  It would just involve potentially less downtime (at a cost to how long it takes and how much DBA time is required).

Comment: This has not changed in 12.1